# Stanford nlp-Coreference resolution - "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I tried to train the statistical coreference resolution system with conll 2012 trial data(http://conll.cemantix.org/2012/data.html).
I wanted to train it for medical data. But I started with conll 2012 trial data inorder to understand the statistical coreference pipeline. 
I took only two ".conll" files of size less than 2MB(eng_0012.conll,eng_0014.conll). These two files contains total of 8 training docs.

I followed below link to build the model.
http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/coref.html
(java -Xmx60g -cp stanford-corenlp-3.7.0.jar:stanford-english-corenlp-models-3.7.0.jar:* edu.stanford.nlp.coref.statistical.StatisticalCorefTrainer -props )

Here the heap size is mentioned as 60g. I used 60g heap size and 15g swap memory and 16 core processor.

But I got "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" exception while building the model.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:261)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:235)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:227)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:458)
    at      edu.stanford.nlp.coref.statistical.Clusterer.getFeatures(Clusterer.java:661)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.statistical.Clusterer.access$700(Clusterer.java:27)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.statistical.Clusterer$State.getActions(Clusterer.java:460)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.statistical.Clusterer.runPolicy(Clusterer.java:225)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.statistical.Clusterer.doTraining(Clusterer.java:167)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.statistical.StatisticalCorefTrainer.doTraining(StatisticalCorefTrainer.java:127)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.statistical.StatisticalCorefTrainer.main(StatisticalCorefTrainer.java:146)
```

When i reduced the training doc for  from 8 to 4 in "doTraining" method of "edu/stanford/nlp/coref/statistical/Clusterer.java" class, it ran successfully.

```
int count = 1;
for (ClustererDoc trainDoc : trainDocs) {
    if (count == 5) {
        break;
    }
    count++;
    examples.add(runPolicy(trainDoc, Math.pow(EXPERT_DECAY(iteration +1))));
}
```

I don't understand why I am  getting this out of memory exception even after giving required configuration for a very small amount of data(less than 2 MB)

Is there any way to optimize the memory usage?

When I went through the source code I found some files like demonyms.txt, gender.data.gz, inanimate.unigrams.txt, state-abbrevations.txt etc. 
Do I need to create any files specifying medical entities for training the medical domain to get better accuracy ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because your heap space is exceeded.

Kindly

```
-Xms512m -Xmx1152m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m
```

look into these in your ide once.
And increase them if needed .

Comment: Look into the link for more info